# How to install Mercurial on my Red Hat Linux machine without using "yum" command?

Tags: linux, mercurial, installation, redhat, yum

I have been trying to install Mercurial binary packages on my Red Hat Linux machine. According to the install instructions, I should type command "yum install mercurial". However, in order to use the "yum" command, I need to first register my system with RHN(Red Hat Network). I tried a couple of times but still failed to do so.

Beside waiting for Red Hat representatives to help me register, I am wondering if there is some way for me to use "yum" command without registering to the RHN. Or even better, can someone tell me how to install Mercurial without using "yum" command ? I have used only "install" command to install it but it didn't work. It is really frustrating~

Thank you very much,

Comment: Did you take a look at the [unix install](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/UnixInstall) instructions? If it didn't work, what error did you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you download mercurial from its [website](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/):
Right-click on the icon (in your downloads folder), and under properties click the box that says "make executable" or something similar.  Then double-click on it, and it should install...

Comment: Hey, I can not find the Linux binary package at the link you mentioned above so I downloaded a mercurial-ssh-1.8.1-1.e15.if.x86_64.rpm file at http://pkgs.repoforge.org/mercurial/. However, it failed to install with an error message of "Missing Dependency: mercurial = 1.8.1-1.el5.rf is needed by package mercurial-ssh-1.8.1-1.el5.rf.x86_64". However, I can not find mercurial-ssh-1.8.1-1.e15.rf.x86_64 anywhere. If you know where to download the complete Red Hat Linux binary package, would you please let me know ? Thanks

Comment: try here http://rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/dag/redhat/el5/x86_64/mercurial-1.8.1-1.el5.rf.x86_64.html  there are a few other links on that page that may help: http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/help.html#main  However, if for whatever reason your RH Linux isn't working, why not just use centOS?  http://www.centos.org/

Comment: I think I downloaded the wrong version of mercurial before. Once I download the one without ssh attached such as mercurial-1.8.1-1.el5.rf.x86_64. It then can work now.:) Thank u all.:)

Answer (score 5):

I've installed last Mercurial version on my CentOS 6.2 x64 from RPMForge, since the "base" repository contain very old Mercurial package only:

a) Install RPMForge repository

wget http://packages.sw.be/rpmforge-release/rpmforge-release-0.5.2-2.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm

rpm --import http://apt.sw.be/RPM-GPG-KEY.dag.txt

rpm -K  rpmforge-release-0.5.2-2.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm

rpm -ivh rpmforge-release-0.5.2-2.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm

b) The default RPMforge repository does not replace any CentOS base packages (In our case - very old Mercurial from base repository). In the past it used to, but those packages are now in a separate repository (rpmforge-extras) which is disabled by default. 
So, I forced to use rpmforge-extras for installation

In this case will installed "mercurial-ssh" itself and "mercurial" by dependency

yum  --enablerepo=rpmforge-extras  install mercurial-ssh

You can install "mercurial" package only

yum  --enablerepo=rpmforge-extras  install mercurial